# Как удалить каждый второй символ в строке?

Tags: c#

Пытался сделать так:

```
string str = textBox1.Text;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i += 2)
{
    builder.Append(str[i].ToString());
}
string result = builder.ToString();
return result;
```

Но вообще ничего не выводится

Comment: В этом коде нет места, где что-то "выводится".

Comment: Но считается правильно.

Comment: После строчки `string result = builder.ToString();` вставь `MessageBox.Show(result);`, если уж хочется "вывести", либо `textBox1.Text = result;`

Comment: Работает. всем спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать короче:

`textBox1.Text = new string(textBox1.Text.Where((c, i) => i % 2 == 0).ToArray());`